# Receive "Not authorized to perform DescribeSecurityGroups" when creating new Project in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to create a new project in AWS CodeBuild. Every time I attempt to I receive the following error:

`Not authorized to perform DescribeSecurityGroups`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

You are likely missing the VPC related permissions in your service role. You need to update the role to have the following policy:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-iam-identity-based-access-control.html#customer-managed-policies-example-create-vpc-network-interface

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow", 
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
            ], 
            "Resource": "*" 
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}:{{account-id}}:network-interface/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Subnet": [
                        "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}:{{account-id}}:subnet/[[subnets]]"
                    ],
                    "ec2:AuthorizedService": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**It means that associated IAM Role doesn't have attached policy allowing CodeBuild to describe Security Groups**.

If you trying to create a new Build project and have selected "New Service Role" *(Create a service role in your account)*, and in the same time added VPC, Subnets and Security Groups in *Additional Configuration* section - you will get *"Not authorized to perform DescribeSecurityGroups"* error.
For some reason AWS auto-created policy looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's not allowing anything VPC/EC2 related, so you can either pre-create correct policy and use it, or let AWS create project without VPC, and modify new policy by adding required services in "Action" block:

```
    "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
        "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue when using cloudformation. The issue was the IAM role was being created before CodeBuild started creation, but the Policy attached the IAM role was being created after CodeBuild was created.

The remedy for this was to add a `DependsOn` to CodeBuild saying it needs the Policy to be created first.

Ex:

```
CodeBuildIamRole: 
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: 'CodeBuildAutomatedTestingRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codebuild.amazonaws.com
      Path: /
  CodeBuildIamPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Sub 'CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy-${AWS::StackName}'
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - 's3:PutObject'
              - 's3:GetObject'
              - 's3:GetObjectVersion'
              - 's3:ListBucket'
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
          - Action:
              - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
              - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
              - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
              - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterface'
              - 'ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions'
              - 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces'
              - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface'
              - 'ec2:DescribeSubnets'
              - 'ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups'
              - 'ec2:DescribeVpcs'
              - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission'
              - 'ecr:*'
              - ...
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              - '*'
      Roles:
        - !Ref CodeBuildIamRole
CodeBuild:
    DependsOn:
      - CodeBuildIamPolicy
    Type: "AWS::CodeBuild::Project"
    Properties:
      ...
```

Hopefully this is helpful